# create pdf file using pdfkit in nodejs

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfkit

I need to generate pdf file in using pdfkit in node.js:

I have this code:

```
doc = new PDFDocument;
doc.pipe; fs.createWriteStream('output.pdf');

doc.fontSize(15);
doc.text('Generate PDF!');

doc.end();
```

And it will create a pdf file: 'output.pdf' , but everytime I open the file, the file is corrupted. It says: **'Unable to open document File type plain text document (text/plain) is not supported'**.

And then I tried:

```
doc = new PDFDocument;
doc.pipe fs.createWriteStream('output.pdf');

doc.fontSize(15);
doc.text('Generate PDF!');

doc.end();
```

But there's an error saying:

```
doc.pipe fs.createWriteStream('output.pdf');
         ^^
Syntax error: Unexpected Identifier
```

Then, what is the right way to generate pdf files in nodejs? Especially in part of:

```
doc.pipe fs.createWriteStream
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9):

Most of their documentation seems to be written in CoffeeScript. As cool as CoffeeScript is, that makes it a pain for those of us writing plain old JS.

So, anywhere you see spaces in their documentation, you should be able to wrap that function in parenthesis:

```
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.pdf'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this piece of code.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');

let options = {
 margins: 50
// you pdf settings here.
}
const doc = new PDFDocument(options);
let out = fs.createWriteStream('output.pdf')
doc.pipe(out);
doc.text('Hellow World.')
doc.end();
out.on('finish', function() {
    // what you want to do with the file.
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the `fs` module before that.
Add this at the top of the file:

```
var fs = require('fs');
```

Comment: it is already called. Already found out the answer. The right syntax for nodejs: doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.pdf'));

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

```
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.pdf'));
```

Comment: but many times generates empty PDF, did you get it any time?, requesting to look my question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/54930985/2034750